# How to run exact suite/spec using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

On the [jasmine page](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) when I click on exact suite/spec filtering works fine for me. But when I'm trying to use it locally on localhost:8000 (simple python server) - it doesn't run any specs...

What could it be? Seems like it's not only my problem, I've seen exact on in the jasmine google group, but there were no solution, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by no specs are running ? Are you getting any error message ?

Comment: I mean: i follow the spec link (which is generated and available for clicking), go to `/?spec=some my spec`, but 0 specs runs.

Comment: If you're using `Karma Runner` you're able to use `iit` and `ddescribe` to run exact spec / suite.